# Zend Framework app not closing mysql connections properly

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm having a weird issue using Zend_Db's PDO adapter for managing my database connections. All of a sudden, I'm constantly hitting the connection limit on my MySQL server.

For whatever reason, every three or four hours or so I end up getting this error, and Apache craps out on every HTTP request with this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[00000] [1129] Host 'my.internal.mysql.server.DNS.here' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'' in

The weird thing is, I haven't changed any code and traffic volumes are actually down from what they've been in the past, so I know my app *shouldn't* be generating more concurrent connections. The weirdest thing is I haven't changed code on any of the main app files in nearly a week and everything has ran swimmingly since.

Rebooting the mysql service or flushing the connections with mysqladmin flush-hosts does do the trick, and I'm sure increasing the max concurrent connections in my.cnf would also help alleviate some of these issues, but there seems to be a core problem with the application itself creating too many connections.

Any thoughts on how I can drill down and correlate the piece of code causing the hanging connection? Externally, all of the different pages of the web app load fine and with good speed.

Comment: I had a tough time deciding whether to post this on ServerFault or here, but I decided to start here since it seems like an app issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think one of your script is running an ultra long query or get stuck ?

The best solution would be to create a logging tool and use that to know where exactly the problem is.

The [Zend_Log](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.log.html) classes should help you to write that logging tool, obviously you have better to user a file writer and not a DB one. Since your problem is DB related you should create or modify the DB class to emit some logs.

I don't know the volumetric of your project but it might have some **performance side effects**.

Also playing with the [long query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) feature of MySQL would probably give you some hint.

Hope you are going to find where is your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to manually close the connection? This seems to be a specific problem.

```
$db->closeConnection();
```

Ref: 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.closing

15.1.8. Closing a Connection

Comment: I shouldn't have to do that - these connections should close by themselves after they've ran.

Comment: Well, no, obviously they aren't - but the point is to determine the cause, not put a bandaid on it.

Comment: I was running into problems with large test suites using Zend_Test with DB connections and manually closing the connection in the teardown helped solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is of any use to you but this link gives you a (temporary) good description of the issue you are experiencing as well as a **--max_connect_errors** setting which you could override:

http://developer.spikesource.com/wiki/index.php/Question:mysqladmin_host_blocked_because_of_many_connection_errors

A user also responds and recommended trying the following on the command line:

```
> mysqladmin -u <user> -p<password> processlist
```

This will give you a list of your current mysql connections to get an idea for how many concurrent connections you are currently running.  Again, these aren't solutions per say, but hopefully they get you a step closer to solving the dropped connection issue.

Answer (score 1):

Our Zend application has also been leaving quite a few connections open.  They tend to come in spurts, but we never did figure out what was going on.  We worked around the problem by setting `max_connections` high (which we needed for other reasons, anyway) and reducing [`wait_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) to two hours.  We could have gotten away with a much lower timeout, but didn't want to risk the real application once we stopped seeing failures.

Comment: I ended up setting my max_connections to 200, but it's still happening even at that. What did you end up setting max connections to?

Answer (score 1):

first i'll ask: do you have any new core-dumps? (check apache error log).

second: from my grim experience having too many connections to the database usually means that you have too many apache processes not dieing properly. Usually this is caused by some long-running process, memory locks, etc. try to `strace` some of your apache processes and see if they hang somewere or do endless loops.

Unless you have a significant increase in traffic you should not suffer from too-many-connection problems

Answer (score 1):

Don't think it's related to properly closing connection.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blocked-host.html says that it rather a problem with network layer.

- If the DB is located on other machine check the network connection problems between (cables, switches, firewalls)
- If the DB is on same machine try connecting using socket, not TCP.

Comment: You may be on to something. It's two different Amazon EC2 instances, and I'm connecting via an internal DNS. I'm not sure what network issues would exist, if any.